# Native Base button with margin in style does not the text inside it

Tags: react-native, native-base

I wrote an app on react native using native base. when I try to put margin in button it will not show the text inside the button. How can I fix it?
When I delete the margin it work fine. but when i put the margin back it do not work. I search many source but no one show any solution at all.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import FloatLabelInput from './src/components/FloatLabelInput';
import {Button, Text} from 'native-base'

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
 render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
     style={styles.background_Image}
     source={require('./media/free-blurry-background-1636594.jpg')}
    />
    <Image source={require('./media/Save-the-Children-Logo.png')} 
    style={{height: '10%', width: '100%'}}/>
    <FloatLabelInput name='Username' security='false'/>
    <FloatLabelInput name='Password' security='true'/>
    <Button block rounded danger
        onPress={() => console.log('my first app')}
        style = {styles.button_style}
        // accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
    > 
      <Text >LOGIN</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
);
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
 },
 welcome: {
  fontSize: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  margin: 10,
 },
instructions: {
 textAlign: 'center',
 color: '#333333',
 marginBottom: 5,
},
background_Image: {
 backgroundColor: '#ccc',
 flex: 1,
 position: 'absolute',
 width: '100%',
 height: '100%',
 justifyContent: 'center',
},
 button_style: {
 margin: '5%'
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug related to percentage by referring to this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19164.. For alternative solution try using px

```
button_style: {
    margin: 5
}
```